# INSERT INTO in BigSQL exception

Tags: biginsights, bigsql

I am creating a table (say `table1`) in Big SQL, and loading the data from HDFS into `table1`. Now from this `table1`, I need to to load data to another table say `table2`, based on certain conditions and on daily basis append more data into this `table2`. Daily new data will be loaded into `table1` and correspondingly new data should come into `table2` as well.

I have tried the following ways

**First**

```
insert append into table table2 as select uri,localtimestamp,count(*) from table1 group by uri order by uri LIMIT 100;
```

> SQL Exception(s) Encountered: [State: 42601][Code: -104]: Error parsing:
>       `insert append into table table2 as select uri,localtimestamp,count(*) from table1 group by uri order by uri LIMIT 100;`

**Second**

```
insert into table table2 as select uri,localtimestamp,count(*) from table1 group by uri order by uri LIMIT 100;
```

> **SQL Exception(s) Encountered:**
>   [State: 58004][Code: 15]: BIGSQL-GEN-0010 Found an internal error:
>   'Failed to execute query '`insert into table table2 as select uri,localtimestamp,count(*) from table1 group by uri order by uri LIMIT 100;':  expected keyword values`'.

**Third**

```
create table if not exists table2(URL_NAME,TODAY_DATE,COUNT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' as select uri,localtimestamp,count(*) from table1 where request_timestamp=localtimestamp group by uri order by uri LIMIT 100;
```

In this case, everyday, new table will be created, while I want the older data to be retained and new data to be added.

**Fourth**

Create table `table2`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table2 (URL_NAME VARCHAR(500),DATE varchar(50),COUNT INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
0 rows affected (total: 0.22s)

insert overwrite table table2 select uri,localtimestamp,count(*) from table1 group by uri order by uri LIMIT 100;
```

> SQL Exception(s) Encountered:
>   [State: 42601][Code: -104]: Error parsing:
>
> `<query>insert overwrite table table2 select uri,localtimestamp,count(*) from table1 group by uri order by uri LIMIT 100;</query> Expecting token <into> after token <insert>`

**Fifth**

```
Load from sql query 'select uri, request_timestamp,1 from table1 where $conditions' split column uri into table table2;
```

> SQL Exception(s) Encountered:
>   [State: 58004][Code: 15]: BIGSQL-GEN-0010 Found an internal error:
>
> 'Failed to execute query '`Load from sql query 'select uri, request_timestamp,1 from table1 where $conditions' split column uri into table table2`':  parse error: keyword hbase or hive expected'.

And if I run with keywords hive

> SQL Exception(s) Encountered:
>   [State: 58004][Code: 15]: BIGSQL-GEN-0010 Found an internal error:
>
> 'Failed to execute query '`Load hive from sql query 'select uri, request_timestamp,1 from table1 where $conditions' split column uri into table table2`'`: 
>   originating expression ends at  (line: 1, column: 143): The statement failed because of an error in the Hive MetaStore. Hadoop log entry identifier: "[4d4e59269]"": 
>   com.ibm.biginsights.catalog.translator.hive.HiveExceptionTranslator$HiveNestedException: FAILED: ParseException line 1:5 mismatched input 'from' expecting DATA near 'load' in load statement

Any idea how to use `INSERT INTO` statement or how to load data from table to another using IBM BigSQL (version 1)

**Update**

---

I tried with `LOAD` as well but getting excpetions

```
LOAD FROM SQL QUERY 'select t1.uri, t1.request_timestamp,t1.cell_lac from sample.web3 t1 where $conditions'  split column t1.uri into table sample.u2_table;
```

> SQL Exception(s) Encountered:
>   [State: 58004][Code: 15]: BIGSQL-GEN-0010 Found an internal error: 'Failed to execute query `'LOAD FROM SQL QUERY 'select t1.uri, t1. request_timestamp,t1.cell_lac from sample.web3 t1 where $conditions' split column t1.uri into table sample.u2_table'`:  parse error:  keyword hbase or hive expected'.

```
LOAD FROM SQL QUERY 'select t1.uri, t1.request_timestamp,t1.cell_lac from sample.web3 t1 where $conditions' split column t1.uri into hive table sample.u2_table;
```

> SQL Exception(s) Encountered:
>   [State: 58004][Code: 15]: BIGSQL-GEN-0010 Found an internal error: 'Failed to execute query `'LOAD FROM SQL QUERY 'select t1.uri, t1.request_timestamp,t1.cell_lac from sample.web3 t1 where $conditions' split column t1.uri into hive table sample.u2_table'`:  parse error: keyword hbase or hive expected'.

```
LOAD FROM TABLE sample.web3 COLUMNS (uri,request_timestamp, cell_lac) INTO hive TABLE sample.u2_table APPEND WITH LOAD PROPERTIES (num.map.tasks = 1);
```

> SQL Exception(s) Encountered:
>   [State: 58004][Code: 15]: BIGSQL-GEN-0010 Found an internal error: 'Failed to execute query `'LOAD FROM TABLE sample.web3 COLUMNS (uri,request_timestamp, cell_lac) INTO hive TABLE sample.u2_table APPEND WITH LOAD PROPERTIES (num.map.tasks = 1)'`:  parse error: keyword hbase or hive expected'.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can't use *INSERT* in that way:

- [Big SQL 1.0 - INSERT and LOAD](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_3.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.bigsql.doc/doc/bsql_load.html)

> The **INSERT** statement inserts a *single row* into an IBM® Big SQL HBase table.

And

> The **LOAD** statements load data into a table. You can load from a remote data source into HBase or Hive. *You can load from **your cluster** or local files into HBase or Hive*.

- [Big SQL 1.0 - LOAD USING ... INTO HBASE or HIVE TABLE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_3.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.bigsql.doc/doc/bsql_load_from.html)

When you want to use local file as using `HIVE DATA` at first you need to use `EXPORT TO`.

Your **fifth** solution is that you want and it should improved:

```
LOAD FROM SQL QUERY 'select uri, request_timestamp,1 from table1 where $conditions' split column uri into table table2;
```

> The columns in the select clause must match both the names and the types of the columns in the target table definition.
>   Otherwise, you must specify the column.names property to specify the mapping to the target columns.

- *1 has no name*
- use an alias for your `table1` like this: `... 'select t1.uri, ... from table1 t1 ... ' SPLIT COLUMN t1.uri ...`
- In another way you can use `LOAD FROM TABLE table1 COLUMNS (uri,request_timestamp, ...) INTO hbase TABLE table2 APPEND WITH LOAD PROPERTIES (num.map.tasks = 1)`

Comment: Will try this and update here. As of now biginsight servers are down :( thanks for reply

Comment: have tried the suggetions you specified but getting exceptions. I have updated the answer to include it